# AngularJS: updating content on url change without reloading

Tags: angularjs, url, reload

I have a simple AngularJS webpage, where a variable acts as a filter. That variable can be given in the URL as, e.g., http://example.org/?filter=foobar. That variable can also be given/selected in a form on the page.

What I want to do is, when the page is already loaded and in the url bar the filter term is changed, for the filter variable to be updated (and so the active filter changed) *without* the page reloading.

This was working for me before, but a recent update and change to html5 mode (for different reasons) seems to have broken this. Now the page is reloaded.

What I did, and still do, is add watchers:

```
$scope.$watch(
    function () { return $location.search().filter },
    function(filter) { $scope.filter = filter; }
);
$scope.$watch(
    'filter',
    function(filter) { $location.search('filter', filter); }
);
```

To be honest, I wrote that code based on examples, so I may not have full understanding.

The other similar questions on SO do not provide answers to my question; they use `$state` or `ngRoute`, which I don't and it worked before without those things.

Comment: What you are describing is job for ui-router: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

You should really take a look into it a bit since this is de facto standard in almost all angularjs apps

Comment: @pegla: ui-router seems geared to mapping states to specific url *paths*. This is not what I am looking for. For me the `filter` variable can take any value and want it appearing in the *query* part of the url, as shown in my question.